# nomalization of complex number in c++

Tags: c++, matlab

I am trying to convert a small code of Matlab in c++.
In matlab normalization of random number can be done easily as below:

```
val = x / norm(x)
```

where x contains random generated real and img part between 0 and 255 as below:

```
70.0000000000000 + 112.000000000000i
11.0000000000000 + 97.0000000000000i
24.0000000000000 + 195.000000000000i
210.000000000000 + 203.000000000000i
177.000000000000 + 47.0000000000000i
81.0000000000000 + 125.000000000000i
243.000000000000 + 114.000000000000i
8.00000000000000 + 165.000000000000i
```

After the normalization, the values in val are as below:

```
0.126554761381164 + 0.202487618209862i
0.0198871767884686 + 0.175368740771041i
0.0433902039021132 + 0.352545406704670i
0.379664284143491 + 0.367008808005375i
0.320002753778085 + 0.0849724826416384i
0.146441938169632 + 0.225990645323507i
0.439325814508897 + 0.206103468535038i
0.0144634013007044 + 0.298307651827029i
```

I really donot know how to do the similar work in c++.
I thought of doing something like below but soon got stuck.

```
int random_real_number;
    int random_img_number;

    vector<int > real_number;
    vector<int> img_number;
    int data_size_val= 8;
    srand (time(NULL));    // Initialize random seed
    for(int i=0;i< data_size_val;i++){
        random_real_number = rand() % 255 + 0;
        std::cout << random_real_number << std::endl;

        random_img_number= rand() % 255 + 0;
        std::cout << random_img_number << std::endl;
        real_number.push_back(random_real_number);
        img_number.push_back(random_img_number);

    }
```

It would be great help if someone can help me in it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to use [std::norm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/norm) for this

Comment: @NathanPierson That doesn't seem to be the same operation as matlab is doing.  Not sure what matlab is doing honestly.

Comment: Ah, good point. It's the square of the Euclidean norm, so the more precise analogue would be [std::abs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/abs)

Comment: MATLAB norm( ) for a vector is simply the Euclidean norm. So for a complex column vector x in MATLAB the equivalent would be sqrt(x' * x), where x' is the complex conjugate transpose. In C/C++ you can run a loop to sum up the individual element-by-element multiplies. E.g., for a term of the form a+b*i you will be summing up a^2+b^2 for that term. Then take the sqrt( ) of the final sum.

Comment: Use `std::complex<double>` to work with complex numbers in C++.

Comment: Thank you @James for providing me the logic.

Comment: When I type in matlab `a=70+112i; a/norm(a)` then I get `0.5300 + 0.8480i`, and when I type `L2=sqrt(70*70+112*112); b=70/L2+i*112/L2` I get that as well. Not sure why your answers are different but dividing by the L2-norm is pretty simple 'even' in C++.

Comment: Thank you @alle_meije for your response. I am still trying to understand conversion formula correctly.

Comment: Can you just try `norm(70+112i)` first? if you get the same as I have, then in C++ that would be trivial via the same computation. But you should really use code like this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/norm#Example

Answer (score 2):

The function `std::norm()` computes something called the field norm, which is the sum of the squares of `real` and `imag`. You get the square root of that with `std::abs()`. So in the same vein as the [example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/norm#Example) on the C++ website, you can do:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {

  std::vector < std::complex < double > >
    zarray {  { 70,  112 }, { 11,  97  }, { 24,  195 }, { 210, 203 },
              { 177, 47  }, { 81,  125 }, { 243, 114 }, { 8,   165 }  };

  for ( auto z: zarray ) {

    assert ( std::norm ( z ) == ( z.real() * z.real() + z.imag() * z.imag() ) );
    assert ( std::norm ( z ) == ( z * std::conj ( z ) ) );
    // assert ( std::norm ( z ) == ( std::abs ( z ) * std::abs ( z ) ) );

    std::cout << "std::abs ( " << std::setw(9)  << z << " ) = "
                               << std::setw(7)  <<     std::abs ( z )
              << ", z/abs = "  << std::setw(19) << z / std::abs ( z ) << '\n';

  }
  
}
```

which should return

```
std::abs (  (70,112) ) = 132.076, z/abs = (0.529999,0.847998)
std::abs (   (11,97) ) = 97.6217, z/abs =  (0.11268,0.993631)
std::abs (  (24,195) ) = 196.471, z/abs = (0.122155,0.992511)
std::abs ( (210,203) ) = 292.077, z/abs = (0.718988,0.695022)
std::abs (  (177,47) ) = 183.134, z/abs = (0.966506,0.256643)
std::abs (  (81,125) ) =  148.95, z/abs =  (0.543808,0.83921)
std::abs ( (243,114) ) = 268.412, z/abs =  (0.905325,0.42472)
std::abs (   (8,165) ) = 165.194, z/abs = (0.048428,0.998827)
```

The first complex number in your example is divided by 553.12, but I don't really see how that would be the L2-norm of 70+112i.

For the C++ experts: compared to the [example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/norm#Example) I had to comment out the last assert because it fails on some of the inputs, I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: The last assert is probably failing because of floating-point errors. When you operate on floating point numbers you are working with an approximation of the real number. As such different calculation paths will yield different results for some input.

Comment: Ah, so the number in the original example used a wisely chosen complex number for which the assertion did not fail.

Comment: Yes and no, it was most likely sheer luck rather than carefully chosen.

For the first assertion: The calculation path for norm is most likely: a^2 + b^2, which means that the calculation path is the same as a*a + b*b

For the second assertion: z*conj(z) = a^2 + abi - abi +b^2 and the function might even just skip the "abi" parts which is approximately the same calculation path.

The last one however is not the same path: sqrt(a^2 + b^2) * sqrt(a^2 + b^2) is not the same calculation path as a^2 + b^2 and as such you can end up with floating point errors.